# Electrode (de)conditioning for breakdown

Tags: electricity

The breakdown voltage between two electrodes in vacuum depends on their surface condition.

If you increase the voltage across the electrodes smoothly, at some voltage $V_0$ you will see the first breakdown. If you go on without caring about the sparking, you will be able to reach a high voltage $V$ at which, after some time, won't induce sparks anymore, as if the electrodes were tired. You might think that the electrodes surfaces are conditioned.

If you turn off all potentials for some period of time, the breakdown potential (i.e., the first breakdown) will fall down back to almost the initial value $V_0$.

Why is this happening?

This is the quote of PhysRev.12.167:

> [Sparks]... were found to show interesting fatigue effects, the initial discharge potential rising from, say 3o,ooo volts per millimeter to 100,000 with continued sparking, as though the spark potential depended upon a surface condition. After the spark potentials had been increased by continuous sparking from say 30,000 to 120,000 volts per millimeter, if the electrodes were allowed to stand, the spark potential would fall in the course of twenty-four hours to about the initial value.

Comment: Sounds like water or other molecules depositing on the metal surface which increased field emission. Did they heat their electrodes to over 200 degrees as a control experiment?

Comment: In ion accelerator conditioning, you will see the pressure in the vacuum beam line start rising, and often can avoid actual sparking by turning down the voltage. Once conditioned, if the tube is kept at reasonable vacuum levels (less than 2E-6 which is adsorbed water vapor) you avoid significant build up of crud (mainly water), and thus don't need conditioning. Given the vacuum technology of the time one would expect that even Millikan would have water, hydrocarbons, and mercury (diffusion pump!) building up on surfaces in the chamber between experiments.